# Change folder ownership in Box

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

We have a situation where we have 2 users, UserA and UserB. I want to transfer all the files and folders of UserB to UserA.

We are using collaborations API to perform this task. But getting following error

> {"type":"error","status":404,"code":"not_found","context_info":{"errors":[{"reason":"invalid_parameter","name":"role","message":"Invalid value 'Owner'. 'role' with value 'Owner' not found"}]},"help_url":"http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors","message":"Not Found","request_id":"304354248562a743910984"}

I get a valid response when I pass anything apart from "owner" as role in request. I don't know what is wrong with "owner" role.

Here is the request

```
POST https://api.box.com/2.0/collaborations/ HTTP/1.1 
As-User: 254598270 
Authorization: Bearer UPSUE228kXGuDBGzy07G5fGxIrDL1QDj 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
Host: api.box.com 
Content-Length: 108 
Expect: 100-continue 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
{"item":{"id":"5092905410","type":"folder"},"accessible_by":{"id":"254608030","type":"user"},"role":"owner"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the documentation might be wrong. Specifying an "owner" role in a collaboration doesn't really make sense given how collaborations work.

However, the [move user's folder](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#move-folder-into-another-users-folder) endpoint might be what you're looking for. It allows you to move the entire root folder of one user into another user's account. Here's an example cURL request:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users/USER_ID/folders/FOLDER_ID \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    -d '{"owned_by": {"id": "USER_ID"}}' \
    -X PUT
```

Note that only the root folder is supported right now (which is folder ID 0). Fortunately, it looks like that's the folder you're trying to move.

Comment: However, you can use collaboration.update_info (python sdk) (there must be a collaboration existing before you update the role to 'owner').

source:
https://community.box.com/t5/Platform-and-Development-Forum/Updating-owned-by-property-has-no-effect/td-p/60394

Comment: only the root folder is supported right now, means, sub folder is not transfered?

Answer (score 0):

All that's missing is that you must add them as an editor prior to making them an owner.

If you follow https://developer.box.com/guides/folders/single/change-owner/

You will see that transferring ownership actually doesn't require a folder move. It is a very simple two (or three) step process:

1. Add the new user as a collaborator of role `EDITOR`
2. Immediately update that collaboration to the role of `OWNER`

That's it. Optionally, you now can remove the collaboration of the original owner, who has been downgraded from owner to editor.

Here is my example using the Python SDK:

```
bc = box.BoxClient()  # This is my own client wrapper
owner = bc.get_user(old_owner.lastname)
user_client = bc.get_user_client(owner.id)  # Get a user_client for the owner
src_folder = user_client.folder(FOLDER_ID)

target = bc.get_user('new_owner.lastname')

new_collab = src_folder.collaborate(target, CollaborationRole.EDITOR)
updated_collaboration = new_collab.update_info(CollaborationRole.OWNER)

# Now we can remove the original owner as collaborator:
for collab in src_folder.get_collaborations():
    target = collab.accessible_by
    if target.id == owner.id:
        collab.delete()
```